# NSSharingService custom link on Facebook via Cocoa?

Tags: facebook, macos, cocoa, facebook-graph-api

I'm using NSSharingService on my OS X app to share image on Facebook.

My code looks like this:

```
items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:shareImage , nil];

NSSharingServicePicker *sharingServicePicker = [[NSSharingServicePicker alloc] initWithItems:items];
sharingServicePicker.delegate = self;

[sharingServicePicker showRelativeToRect:NSZeroRect
                                  ofView:sender
                           preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
```

Where shareImage is a NSImage.

When I post this on Facebook, I get the image fine, but I also get a link on the Facebook post called "OS X" and when I click this link, it redirects me to the Apple OS X page.

I want to customize this link to advertise my app instead of advertising OS X.  Is this possible?  Or do I need to use a different method to setup the sharing service?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) directly. That way, all posts published will be attributed to your app, and not to OS X.